# Why is my button not outputting data to the graph?

Tags: swift, xcode, plot, swift3

So I've narrowed my problem down considerably and I think I found the turning point.

I've been following an example that has a button and a Custom View. The button calculates some value of the mathematical function `exp(-x)` and then outputs a graph to the Custom View.

I have done the same in my project: I have a button and a Custom View. I set up the Action in the same manner. I made sure to give the Custom View the same class name as in the example. But for some reason my setup isn't working.

This is the code (this function is located within the View Controller class):

```
@IBAction func calculateWavefunction(_ sender: Any) {


    // calculate exp(-x)

    for i in 0 ..< 60 {

        let x = -2.0 + Double(i) * 0.2
        let y = exp(-x)


        let dataPoint: plotDataType = [.X: x, .Y: y]
        contentArray.append(dataPoint)
    }

    makePlot(xLabel: "X", yLabel: "Y", xMin: -0.5, xMax: 1.5, yMin: -0.25, yMax: 1.25)
    contentArray.removeAll()

}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Please share the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: @DaveWeston I've been looking through an example and trying to understand it. I think if I can understand it then I can understand the problem with my project. I'll edit the question with the example's code then.

Comment: I assume the example code works fine as is. You need to share what changes you're trying to make to it, and what problems you're having.

Comment: @DaveWeston edited. I'm only trying to learn from this plotting example in order to implement into my own project. This example is extremely close to what I need to do.